# Create dialog box with 2 radio buttons inside

Tags: android

I want to create a dialog box when a button is clicked inside the dialog box I need 2 radio buttons which are linked with mobile default music and other is external memory of the mobile. Anyone can help me out this here is my code as follows?

```
    buttonSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sound);
        buttonSound.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
                Log.d("TAG","button inside mobile");
                alertDialogBuilder
                //.setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Sound",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        AlarmActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  });
//              builder.setPositiveButton("Sound", );
                alertDialogBuilder
                //.setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                                                                                                            .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("SdCard",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity

                        Log.d("TAG","button inside sdCard");
                        AlarmActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  });
                 alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

And it is showing error as follows given below

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change this..

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AlarmActivity.this);
```

**EDIT**

**radio_btn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/status_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/default_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Default music" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/external_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="External card music" />

</RadioGroup>
```

**JAVa**

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_btn, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
    RadioButton default_btn = (RadioButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.default_btn);
    RadioButton external_btn = (RadioButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.external_btn);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AlarmActivity.this);
                Log.d("TAG","button inside mobile");
                alertDialogBuilder
                //.setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(dialoglayout);
                .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        AlarmActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  });
                 alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: but it is showing only one option in the dialog box. i need to show 2 option one is default music files of the phone and other is external card music files

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlarmActivity.this` or this intead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Create in layout in res/layout

1. **radio_dialog_layout.xml**

   ```
   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/rd_!"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="A" />

   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/rd_2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/rd_!"
       android:text="B" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/rd_2"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:text="OK" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. create dialog in activity by using this code:

   ```
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.radio_dialog_layout);
   dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   // there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!
   // set up radiobutton
   RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rd_);
   RadioButton rd2 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rd_2);

   // now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it
   dialog.show();
   ```

You can also refer this tutorials: [How to add lists, Checkboxes and Radio buttons to an AlertDialog – Android](http://www.javabeat.net/lists-checkboxes-radio-buttons-alertdialog-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Create one xml file,

```
 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hi" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiobutton1"
    android:text="Bye" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiobutton2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Click" />
```

and create Dialog in activity,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dialog.setTitle("My Dialog Box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    // set up radiobutton inside dialog box
    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton2);

    // Show the dialog
    dialog.show();
```